# Fortran 95 data list on multiple lines

Tags: arrays, list, fortran, fortran77, fortran95

```
   integer M

   character (len = 20) dict(50)

   data dict/'gum','sin','for','cry','lug','bye','fly','ugly', 
 M           'each','from','work','talk','with','self',
 M           'pizza','thing','feign','fiend','elbow','fault',
 M           'dirty','budget','spirit','quaint','maiden',
 M           'escort','pickax','example','tension','quinine',
 M           'kidney','replica','sleeper','triangle',
 M           'kangaroo','mahogany','sergeant','sequence',
 M           'moustache','dangerous','scientist','different',
 M           'quiescent','magistrate','erroneously',
 M           'loudspeaker','phytotoxic','matrimonial',
 M           'parasympathomimetic','thigmotropism'/
```

I was given some code in Fortran 77 and I must convert it to 95. I know very basic stuff on the data keyword like

```
character (len = 5) arr (5)
data arr /'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'/
```

I don't know how I would do the above on separate lines. I'm guessing it has something to do with the above above but I can't figure out what the M is used for in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fortran 77, any character in column 6 denotes a continuation line.  "M" in this case.  In Fortran 95 you instead use an ampersand on the end of the line to be continued.

Comment: I see. I just made the changes and received syntax errors on the & character. I changed the file extension from .for to .f95 and this resolved the error. I assumed that file extensions didn't matter because it's just a text file..

Comment: Some compilers use the file extension to identify the source code form.

Comment: This is not correct. The distinction you make is not between fortran 77 and fortran 95, but instead between fixed source form and free source form. Of course, in fortran 77 only (what is now called) fixed form was valid, and fortran 90 introduced free form, but fixed form remains part of the standard.

Comment: The gfortran manual referring to -ffree-form and -ffixed-form: "When neither option is specified, the source form is determined by the file extension."   If you want an unusual combination (free-form source with F77 or fixed with F95) its possible, otherwise gfortran will select the sensible default based on the file extension.

Comment: As a side note, if you want the code to be compatible with both `free` form and `fixed` form, you can put an ampersand at the end of the line you want to continue in column 73 **AND** an ampersand on the next line in column 6.